# SQL performance issues with window functions on daily basis

Tags: sql, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cumulative-sum

Given ~23 million users, what is the most efficient way to compute the cumulative number of logins within the last X months for any given day (even when no login was performed) ? Start date of a customer is its first ever login, end date is today.

**Desired output**

```
c_id        day            nb_logins_past_6_months
----------------------------------------------
1           2019-01-01     10
1           2019-01-02     10
1           2019-01-03     9
...
1           today          5
```

➔ One line per user per day with the number of logins between current day and 179 days in the past

**Approach 1**

```
 1. Cross join each customer ID with calendar table
 2. Left join on login table on day
 3. Compute window function (i.e. `sum(nb_logins) over (partition by c_id order by day rows between 179 preceding and current row)`)

+ Easy to understand and mantain
- Really heavy, quite impossible to run on daily basis
- Incremental does not bring much benefit : still have to go 179 days in the past
```

**Approach 2**

```
 1. Cross join each customer ID with calendar table 
 2. Left join on login table on day between today and 179 days in the past
 3. Group by customer ID and day to get nb logins within 179 days

+ Easier to do incremental
- Table at step 2 is exceeding 300 billion rows
```

What is the common way to deal with this knowing this is not the only use case, we have to compute other columns like this (nb logins in the past 12 months etc.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you would use:

```
select l.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customerid
                      order by login_date
                      range between interval '6 month' preceding and current row
                     ) as num_logins_180day
from logins l;
```

This assumes that the `logins` table has a date of the login with no time component.

I see no reason to multiply 23 million users by 180 days to generate a result set in excess of 4 million rows to answer this question.

Comment: Because I want to have the count for any given day. We use this to group customers into buckets (ie. `advanced` are the ones who have between 100 and 200 logins within the past 6 months so we're able to say we have X `advanced` users on day 2019-01-14 for instance). If the customer did not login on a day, we'll not have the count using your query.

Comment: @nicnhus . . . The volume of data that this question describes is humongous.  I might suggest that you ask a new question if all you want is the *summary* of "advanced" users on each day.  Much simpler problem to solve.

Comment: The summary of "advanced" isn't the only KPI we are monitoring. We have not other choice than to compute the value of logins past 6 months, logins past 12 months, etc. **everyday**. We are for instance analyzing the bahviors of cohorts of "advanced" users so we need to know for any given day which customers are "advanced" or not ; not just the summary of "advanced" users.

Comment: @nicnhus . . . It should be sufficient to have the summaries of the start and stop dates of "advanced" users for each user.  I imagine that is a much smaller amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, don't do the entire task all at once.  Instead, gather subtotals at the end of each month (or day or whatever makes sense for your data).  Then `SUM` up the subtotals to provide the 'report'.

More discussion (with a focus on MySQL):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

(You should tag questions with the specific product; different products have different syntax/capability/performance/etc.)